# vim leaving empty display on exit

Tags: macos, vim, zsh

I'm on OSX using `zsh` and `vim` clears my screen on exit, unlike `less` or `man` and other applications. When I exit `vim`, the next command prompt is on the very bottom of the screen, leaving empty lines between the prompt that opened `vim` and the following prompt.

What exactly is causing this?

My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`.

Here's a screenshot showing the difference:
[image: screenshot]

I want `vim` to behave like `man` on the right side.